# How can I disable $logProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging

I am confused with `$logProvider`... 
I have disabled the logs messages, but I am still getting the log.

Can any one help me what wrong in this code?

```js
angular
    .module("myModule", []).config(function ($logProvider) {
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
    })
    .controller("myController", ['$scope','$log', function ($scope, $log) {
        $log.debug("This is sample text");
        $log.warn("This is sample text");
        $log.error("This is sample text");
        $log.info("This is sample text");
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule" >
    <div ng-controller="myController">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If it helped you, can you accept one of the answers? :)

Answer (score 1):

`$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);` only disable the **debug level** of `$log`, that is why you can still use `$log.warn`, `$log.error` and `$log.info`.

More about that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$logProvider).

---

If you want to completely turn off `$log`, check this [link](http://nahidulkibria.blogspot.fr/2014/01/turn-onoff-log-in-angularjs-completely.html) and especially this part of the code:

```
$logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

$provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    $delegate.table = angular.noop;
    return $delegate;
}]);
$provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    $delegate.info = angular.noop;
    return $delegate;
}]);
$provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    $delegate.warn = angular.noop;
    return $delegate;
}]);
$provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    $delegate.error = angular.noop;
    return $delegate;
}]);
```

Comment: What does decorator do?

Comment: $delegate also?

Comment: `decorator` is used to override an implementation. Check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) which explain well how decorators works.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you...

```js
  angular.module("myModule", [])
    .config(['$provide',
      function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate',
          function($delegate) {
            var origDebug = $delegate.debug;

            $delegate.debug = function() {
              var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
              args[0] = [new Date().toString(), ': ', args[0]].join('');
              origDebug.apply(null, args)
            };

            return $delegate;
          }
        ]);
      }
    ])

  .controller("myController", ['$scope', '$log',
    function($scope, $log) {
      $log.debug("This is sample text");
      $log.warn("This is sample text");
      $log.error("This is sample text");
      $log.info("This is sample text");
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">

  </div>

</div>
```